# Then, find $\lim \left ( x_{n+ 1}- x_{n} \right )$

Tags: limits

Prove that for every postive integer $n$, the equation $2012^{x}\left ( x^{2}- n^{2} \right )= 1$ has a unique solution ( denoted by $x_{n}$). Then, find $$\lim \left ( x_{n+ 1}- x_{n} \right ).$$

Comment: What is the motivation? Where does this problem come from?

Comment: @JoshuaRuiter: why would that be relevant?

Answer (score 3):

If $-n\le x\le n$ then $2012^x(x^2-n^2)\le0$, so no solution.

If $x<-n$, consider $y(x)=2012^x\cdot x^2$. Then
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2012^x\left(x^2\ln2012+2x\right)=2012^x\cdot x(x\ln2012+2)$$
Now, $2012^x>0$, $x<-n<0$, and $x\ln2012+2<-n\ln2012+2\le-\ln2012+2<0$, so
$$\frac{dy}{dx}>0$$
And $y(x)$ is increasing on $(-\infty,-n)$, so
$$2012^x(x^2-n^2)<2012^x\cdot x^2<2012^{-n}\cdot n^2\le2012^{-1}<1$$
So no solution in this case, either.

If $x>n$ then
$$\frac d{dx}\left[2012^x(x^2-n^2)-1\right]=2012^x\left((x^2-n^2)\ln2012+2x\right)>2012^x(2x)>0$$
So there can be at most one positive root $x_n$. Since $2012^n\left(n^2-n^2\right)=0$ and
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}2012^x\left(x^2-n^2\right)=\infty$$
There is exactly one positive root.

We have
$$0\le x_n^2-n^2=\frac1{2012^{x_n}}<\frac1{2012^n}$$
So
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(x_n^2-n^2\right)=0$$
By the squeeze theorem. Since $x_n>n$, $x_n+n>2n>1$, so
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(x_n-n\right)=0$$
Then
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(x_{n+1}-x_n\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left((x_{n+1}-n-1)-(x_n-n)+1\right)=0-0+1=1$$